# Regex as associative array key?

Tags: regex, d, associative-array

I'm working on a very performance dependent portion of my code in D. For this, I want to have an associative array mapping my data to a `Regex` so that I can use it later.

When I try to do this, it gives me the error, `index is not a type or expression`. How can I use this regex as my array key?

Edit: For code, here's what I'm trying to define in my class:

```
View[Regex] m_routes;
```

I want that so that I can add the routes like below:

```
void add(string route, View view)
{
    auto regex = regex(route.key, [ 'g', 'i' ]);

    if (regex in m_routes)
        throw new Exception(format(`Route with path, "%s", is already assigned!`, route));

    m_routes[regex] = view;
}
```

This would then allow me to check the regex against a route, without having to rebuild each one, shown in this method:

```
View check(string resource)
{
    foreach (route; m_routes.byKeyValue())
    {
        auto match = matchAll(resource, route.key);

        // If this regex is a match
        // return the view
        if (!match.empty)
        {
            return route.value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide some sample code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis added some code for what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems std.regex.Regex is an alias that takes a type parameter:

(from std.regex.package, line 289 in release 2.071.0)

```
public alias Regex(Char) = std.regex.internal.ir.Regex!(Char);
```

In other words, you'll need to specify the char type for the regex. For `string`, that'd be `char`:

```
View[Regex!char] m_routes;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it!

Accepted as the answer.